# Conditionally summing the contents of one column based on another ... in one formula

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with data in columns A, B, and C (small sample shown below).

If Columns E and F I have a list of every potential combination of A and B, in addition to some values which were not used

Column G sums the values of column C, where E&F is the same as A&B

```
A     B     C     D     E     F     G
a     slw   12          a     slw   30
a     slw   18          a     qux   16
a     qux   16          a     xkc   0
b     anh   10          b     anh   46
b     anh   18          b     ilk   22
b     anh   18          c     jpw   14
b     ilk   12          c     yev   0
b     ilk   10          c     qux   28
c     jpw   14
c     qux   18
c     qux   10
```

Here is the formula I am currently using to fill in a single cell, say G1: `=SUM(QUERY({ARRAYFORMULA($A:$A&$B:$B),$C:$C)},"Select Col3 Where Col1='"&E1&F1&"'"))`

This formula does in fact work. I can drag it down for the entire column G. Except, I am looking to condense this into a single formula in G1 which fills the entire column. I have tried enclosing the query in an Arrayformula, however this didn't work. I've also tried a number of other methods swapping for FILTER and the like.

I'm not sure if this is actually possible, but for reasons difficult to explain here I need to avoid copying the formula into each cell. I'm still looking for a solution, but wondering if anyone has some ideas how I could go about potentially getting QUERY to nest within an ARRAYFORMULA. Note that I am willing to use custom functions, but would prefer to avoid them. Also, keep in mind that my current formula is here more as an example of what I've tried, to help better explain what I'm trying to do; feel free to completely discard it.

Comment: If you add a link to a test sheet with the data above and the formula, you have a better chance that someone try to respond. If no one has responded I will have a look tomorrow AM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the documentation to Query() and the GSheet's subset of SQL, what you need is the GROUP BY clause. Another solution that might work immediately is a Pivot Table.

```
=query(A8:C18, "select A, B, sum(C) group by A, B")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, not sure why I didn't think of it earlier seeing as I've used the Group By clause before. I'll try adjusting it for my actual data soon.